# remove a class from everything not in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove a class from all elements of the .column class that are not in the viewport / browser window?

Currently, since I know how to add a class to all things in the viewport, my current plan is to add a class to all elements of the column class in the viewport. Let's call that class .inViewport. Then using the CSS `:not()` inside a JQuery selector to remove the class from all .column that are not having that .inViewport class;and, therefore, not in the viewport.

So,

```
/* add .inViewport to all .column in viewport */
 `$('.column:not(.inViewport)').removeclass('animated');` // remove class .animated from all .column not in viewport.
```

Is there a better way to remove the class .animated from all .column not in viewport / window?

Comment: Well, if the routine represented by your first comment already iterates over all columns to mark those who satisfy the "in viewport" condition, it should be simple to refactor it so it removes the `animated` class from those who do not satisfy the condition instead.

Comment: if it works, why not leave it?